# docker: "first record does not look like a TLS handshake" error when pull image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-registry

I have just installed docker and then try running `hello-world`program.
My server is behind proxy of company. So, I set proxy environment variables according to manual from docker in a file named `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@server:8080"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:password@server:8080"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

But, while run `$ sudo docker run hello-world`. I get the error

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

This is `docker version`:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.9
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        9d988398e7
 Built:             Fri May 15 00:25:34 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.9
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       9d988398e7
  Built:            Fri May 15 00:24:07 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.6
  GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8
  GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

This is `docker info` ( I hidden informations about proxy of my company ):

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 19.03.9
 Storage Driver: overlay
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc version: 425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.15.0-65-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 48
 Total Memory: 31.31GiB
 Name: SPP00007867
 ID: EEZD:GC4D:IWYF:2MVR:RLXW:MAZU:EQPV:A3FY:RFUY:6NXP:EJNG:TRMD
 Docker Root Dir: /mnt/docker-data
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http://xxxxx:xxxxx@xxx:8080
 HTTPS Proxy: http://xxxxx:xxxxx@xxx:8080
 No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: the overlay storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.
```

Can anyone help me ? Thank All !!!

Comment: does your proxy support https ? try chaging 
`Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:password@server:8080"` to 
`Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@server:8080"`

Comment: Thanks! follow you guide, I get an other error ```docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority```. What should I do next ?

Comment: What is the output for this one ?
`sudo HTTP_PROXY=<your-proxy-value> docker run hello-world`

Comment: The ouput is ```docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority``` too.

Comment: Could you update your questions with output for `docker version` and `docker info` ?

Comment: I have just editted the post. Thanks !

Comment: I have the same x509 problem tough my proxy setup are looks correct.

Answer (score 28):

I had this exact issue and it was due to HTTPS_PROXY not having the correct variable (https instead of http) assigned to it in both bashrc and docker desktop settings configuration

Comment: This is what caused issue in my case. My HTTPS_PROXY environment variable was using `https://<host>:<httpsPort>` instead of `http://<host>:<httpsPort>`. Changing to http solved my problem.

Comment: In my case, the network traffic was somehow getting blocked and my proxy. Nothing in the logs indicated this! However when I added the host to my proxy whitelist, everything worked fine!